# Microsoft Graph - Adding recurring event with exceptions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

How can I add a recurring event **with exceptions** using the Microsoft Graph API?
Is this possible in Microsoft Graph at all?

Edit:

For instance, I want to create an event that will take place every Monday, starting 07/05/2021, but that will not occur on 07/12/2021.
I already know how to create the recurring event, but I don't know how to create it with this exception.

Comment: What do you mean when you say with exceptions? Have you checked [Create recurring event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-create-a-recurring-event)  and [patternedRecurrence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/patternedrecurrence?view=graph-rest-1.0) 
 specifications

Comment: I mean that some dates have been removed from the recurring event. I can have an event every Monday, except in the date 07/12/21. I've read these docs, but there is nothing about this subject in them. There is something about query, but not about how to create exceptions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Answer (score 1):

You first need to find the correct [Event Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) you want to change.

```
/events/{id}/instances?startDateTime={dateTime}&endDateTime={dateTime}
```

This will return a list of instances within the specified date range. You then parse the list for the specific instance you want to obtain its unique `id` and delete it like any normal event.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. I was hoping to create the event already with the exceptions, but that's better than nothing.

Comment: @Marc I used that API it's working but it is returning only 10 instances of the recurring series, not all what i can do to get all instances in the specified date range?